# How to get public photos JSON of any user - not necessarily in your friend list - using Graph API of Facebook search at a particular Location?

Tags: ios, objective-c, facebook-graph-api, facebook-fql, facebook-ios-sdk

I want to integrate Facebook Graph Api for location based photo search to get all the public photos post URL in a JSON file.

When we search, for example, "Photos taken in Bhubaneswar, India" on Facebook's home page, we are getting a lots of public (from those who may or may not be friends) photos. That feature Facebook added.

My question is how to get that JSON file with public photos array, that is, what should be the FQL query to get that JSON file?

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/examples/

http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/